# Why would vim create a new file every time you save a file?

Tags: linux, vim

I have a file named `test`:

```
[test@mypc ~]$ ls -i

4982967 test
```

Then I use vim to change its content and enter `:w` to save it.

It now has a different inode:

```
[test@mypc ~]$ ls -i

4982968 test
```

That means it's a different file already, why would vim save it to another file as I use `:w` to save to the original one?

You see, echo to a file will not change the inode, which is expected:

```
[test@mypc ~]$ echo v >> test

[test@mypc ~]$ ls -i

4982968 test
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is trying to protect you from disk and os problems. It writes out a complete copy of the file, and when it is satisfied this has finished properly, renames this file to the required filename.  Hence, new inode number.

If there were a crash during the save process, the original file would remain untouched, possibly saving you from losing the file completely.

Comment: Right, and this behavior can be influenced with the `'backupcopy'` option.

Comment: Why couldn't it write out a complete copy of the file, and when it's satisfied this has finished properly, write to the original file?

Comment: @bobbyjack That’s what the rename step accomplishes.  Why write out the file twice, when you can just rename the new good file over the old one, much more quickly, and with better file system guarantees?  If you have backup versions turned on, it can also keep the old file and rename it to a .bak file.

Comment: Why write out the file twice? To avoid bugs caused by creating a new one! I appreciate that there's a setting to allow you to do just that, which is far better than some alternative editors which just clobber your file and leave things broken without asking...