# Why does :w! work but not :wq? File is read only error

Tags: vi

Why does <kbd>:wq</kbd> fail with `File is read only`, but <kbd>:w!</kbd> then <kbd>:q</kbd> succeeds?

This file was opened by the command `sudo vi filename` since the permissions are 550

Comment: The `!` in `:w!` means write the file anyway despite non-writeable permission.  This will change the inode number of the file, though.

Comment: a new inode is not unique to the `!` in the command, this is default `w` behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sudo command allows you to override the permissions of the file 550 (rxrx-).  `:wq` won't override but `:w!` will.

Note that the purpose of the `!` is to 'force' your command `w`.  `:wq` doesn't include the 'force' modifier.

Answer (score 4):

`:w!` will write to a read-only file if the directory is writeable, even if the file itself is not writeable. (It creates a new file, and deletes the old one)

Comment: vi(m) always creates a new file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093425/why-would-vim-create-a-new-file-every-time-you-save-a-file

Comment: Vim  does by default; vi doesn't. Vim has a 'backupcopy' option, which is set to 'auto' by default, meaning that normally it makes new files.